# Ingress with IP address instead of host

Tags: kubernetes, networking, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm self-hosting a few applications on my NAS, like tt-rss. I normally run them with docker-compose. To access an app like this when I'm not on my local network, I point a port of my home router to the port of my NAS where the app is running, and then I can just access the app through `htpp://public_ip_router_here:port_number/tt-rss`.

I decided to move these apps to a k8s cluster. For "fun", but also because I can setup my ingress controller to do the TLS termination, and I would unlock https for all my apps.

The cluster is running (provisioned with microk8s). TLS works too, with some conditions:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: fanout-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: fancy_domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: api
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - fancy_domain.com
    secretName: tls-secret
```

If I modify my `/etc/hosts` file (I run Linux), and put this inside:

```
192.168.0.203 fancy_domain.com
```

I can access my service through `https://fancy_domain.com`. This works perfectly, but it's a bit annoying because it would force me to modify my `/etc/hosts` file on all the devices I use. Is there a way to use an IP address instead of hostname? Or any workaround really, as long as I can do the fanout and keep the TLS termination.

I tried something like this but weirdly, I'm getting a 404 error then:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minimal-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx-example
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: api
            port:
              number: 8080
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - 192.168.0.203
    secretName: tls-secret
```

Comment: No, TLS/HTTPS cannot use an IP, as that would defeat the point. The idea is to prevent websites from impersonating, and encrypt traffic. However, traffic is encrypted with keys. You can set localhost to a certificate and host there instead of a different domain. This is what I would recommend, but also, do you really need https for a local website? Obviously for cookies too but it is painful when you are distributing your software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I can't use an IP in the ingress, but:

- I created a self-signed certificate for a random domain name
- I put the certificate into a secret
- I built my ingress using the random domain name
- I modified the `/etc/hosts` files of all the devices that had to access the domain name. On Android, "Virtual Hosts" works like a charm

This works perfectly for a test setup.

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://traefik.me
You get TLS certificates and DNS for your services. I recommend to only use it for development purposes.

For a more elaborate setup, get a domain/DNS yourself, point it to your router and let the router forward port 443 to your cluster. You can get TLS certificates for your domain without cost using Let's Encrypt.